# Google sign in with flutter does not work on android, userCredential.user is null

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-signin

I am using google sign in on flutter and my code works perfectly on ios but not on android. after signing in with credential, userCredential.user returns null.

```
Future loginWithGoogle() async {
    //  login with google
    final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
        await googleUser!.authentication;
    final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );

    try {
      final UserCredential userCredential =
          await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

      print(userCredential);

      final users = db.collection('users');
      await users.doc(userCredential.user!.uid).set({
        "name": userCredential.user!.displayName ?? "User",
        'email': userCredential.user!.email,
        "password": "google",
        'createdAt': DateTime.now(),
        'updatedAt': DateTime.now(),
      }, SetOptions(merge: true));

      if (userCredential.user != null) {
        return {"status": true};
      } else {
        return {
          "status": false,
          "msg": "Something went wrong. Please try again later."
        };
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'account-exists-with-different-credential') {
        return {
          "status": false,
          "msg": "The account already exists with a different credential."
        };
      } else if (e.code == 'invalid-credential') {
        return {
          "status": false,
          "msg": "Error occurred while accessing credentials. Try again."
        };
      } else if (e.code == "user-not-found") {
        return {"status": false, "msg": "User not found. Please try again."};
      } else {
        debugPrint(e.toString());
        return {
          "status": false,
          "msg": "Something went wrong. Please try again later."
        };
      }
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
      return {
        "status": false,
        "msg": "Something went wrong. Please try again later."
      };
    }
  }
```

I have checked that I have added SHA-1, SHA-256 keys, as well as google-service.json. But it still doesnt work.